# Pod GoogleMaps not working

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I know this is very basic, but not able to debug the problem. This is my Podfile.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

I picked this from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start). When I try `pod install`, I get

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `GoogleMaps`
```

verbose says:

```
  Preparing

Updating local specs repositories

Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /usr/bin/git pull --ff-only
  Already up-to-date.

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  - GoogleMaps

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
[!] Unable to find a specification for `GoogleMaps`

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:388:in `handle_resolver_error'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:69:in `rescue in resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:56:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:535:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:533:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:70:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:210:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:133:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:132:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:104:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:71:in `run_install_with_update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:101:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What happens when you try to do a `pod search GoogleMaps`? I copied your exact Podfile on a new project and was able to run `pod install` successfully.

Comment: How did you solve your issue? Did the proposed answer work for you?

Answer (score 7):

**Start fresh:**

1. Create a new, clean `Xcode` project
2. `pod init`
3. Add the lines below in `Podfile`
4. `pod install`

**Podfile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'

target 'SO-32079263' do
pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

**pod install**
*tested with 0.37.1*

```
Analyzing dependencies

Downloading dependencies
Installing GoogleMaps (1.10.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

---

**Less fresh:** *(See [Jatin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4684764/jatin) comment)*

*Alternate step 2:* `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile Podfile.lock ; pod init`

Comment: just delete podfile if exists in your directory. then follow the above steps.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

- Install cocoa pods

  > sudo gem install cocoapods
- Create a new, Xcode project (Project Name example: My Project)
- Go to the project folder and create a new file with the name **Podfile**
- Open pod file and enter the config below - Change "My Project" to your project name.

>

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'My Project' do
pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

In Terminal, navigate to project folder and type **pod install**

> pod install

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using GoogleMaps (1.13.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things Here is the fix!!

**Imp:** Make sure that you have these lines in your PodFile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'YOUR_APPLICATION_TARGET_NAME_HERE' do
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```

If the above is fine then you need to update the pods:
try the following steps:

1. Open a new terminal and run the following command in a temp directory.

   `pod try GoogleMaps`

keep patience! It will take some time but will update the pod.

2. Now try to install the pod in ur project again. It should work.Else try to run the following commands in the project dir:

`pod repo update`

try again.
Comment in the case of any issue!!