# Can't install GoogleMaps with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoapods, xcode8

I want to install the GoogleMap SDK for iOS in my project. But when I installed with pod install it got an error.

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `GoogleMaps`
```

`pod repo remove master ; pod setup` doesn't help. `pod repo update --verbose`

```
    Updating spec repo `.git`
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/admin/.cocoapods/repos/.git fetch origin
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     42723a4..830f47f  master     -> origin/master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/admin/.cocoapods/repos/.git rev-parse --abbrev-ref
  HEAD
  HEAD
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/admin/.cocoapods/repos/.git reset --hard origin/HEAD
  fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
  Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
  'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `.git` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`
```

My podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Interests' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Interests
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
  target 'InterestsTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'InterestsUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `pod repo update --verbose`?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079263/pod-googlemaps-not-working

Comment: you left out an "end" word after your `target 'Interests' do`.... you have 3 "target" commands and only two "end" commands

Comment: @JAL, of couse. I edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30441332) of reinstalling via brew which fixed the issue.

```
 /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
brew install cocoapods --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and when I try to follow your command, I get this issue. Error: invalid option: --with-brewed-curl

Comment: use /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the Specs repo at the top of the Podfile as follows:

`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`

I can see this is the case because of the error you have listed:

```
Updating spec repo `.git`
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `.git` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`
```

Comment: I mean, the Podfile was definitely broken without it and I can see you updated your question to reflect the changes from this.