# Getting error for installing google maps library

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoapods

I'm trying to install googlemaps library using cocoapods but getting error for it. I've tried these solutions ([S1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901278/cant-install-googlemaps-with-cocoapods/41924543#41924543), [S2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385939/git-clone-fails-with-sslread-error-on-os-x-yosemite/30441332#30441332)) but getting the same error again and again.

This is the error.
 [image]

If I remove google maps from pod file, it works perfectly fine.

here is my pod file

```
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 1.1.0'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'DropDown'
  pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'SearchTextField'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

Comment: Can you please show your podfile?

Comment: May you can try it https://stackoverflow.com/a/49798271/2776008

Comment: @HardikS I'v updated my question so you can see my pod file as well.

Comment: May be you need to use VPN to connect with Google Developer.

Comment: Have you followed the exact instructions from [this guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)?